# XNA game items drag and drop — how to implement object exchange?

Tags: c#, swap

I'm making an inventory system and I'm stuck at the part where the items should be moved from cell to cell by simple drag'n'dropping.

There is an `Item[,] Inventory` array which holds the items, `object fromCell, toCell` which should hold the references to cells to operate with when mouse button is released, but when I try doing this:

```
object temp = toCell;
toCell = fromCell;
fromCell = temp;
```

...the game is only swapping object references and not the actual objects. How do I make this work?

**UPD:** Thanks to Bartosz I figured this out. Turns out you can safely use a reference to array of objects and change *it* with saved indices of objects you wish to swap.

Code can be like this:

```
object fromArray, toArray;
int fromX, fromY, toX, toY;

// this is where game things happen

void SwapMethod()
{
    object temp = ((object[,])toArray)[toX, toY];
    ((object[,])toArray)[toX, toY] = ((object[,])fromArray)[fromX, fromY];
    ((object[,])fromArray)[fromX, fromY] = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using indexes to your `Inventory` array: `int fromCell, toCell`.

```
var temp = Inventory[toCell];
Inventory[toCell] = fromCell;
Inventory[fromCell] = temp;
```

You're modeling inventory as 2D array of slots, so it seems fairly safe to use indexes to access it.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
internal static void Swap<T>(ref T one, ref T two)
{
    T temp = two;
    two = one;
    one = temp;
}
```

And all your swapping becomes this.

```
Swap(Inventory[fromCell], Inventory[toCell]);
```

Also, you can add the extension for the arrays (if more confortable).

```
public static void Swap(this Array a, int indexOne, int indexTwo)
{
    if (a == null)
        throw new NullReferenceException(...);

    if (indexOne < 0 | indexOne >= a.Length)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(...);

    if (indexTwo < 0 | indexTwo >= a.Length)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(...);

    Swap(a[indexOne], a[indexTwo]);
}
```

To use it like so:

```
Inventory.Swap(fromCell, toCell);
```

Comment: Question is, can you pass reference to an object obtained as a result of an indexer method?

Comment: My bad, of course it's possible for arrays, it's just not possible for custom indexers (`this[index]`).

Comment: The first one simply doesn't work because I'm not getting the `from` and `to` cells in one method, and the seconds seems a little overkill for a single use. But thanks anyway.